# Is it possible to run commands in Katalon?

Tags: testing, cmd, integration, katalon-studio

Katalon is popular in automation testing. I have already used it in our project and it works amazingly.

Now, What I want to achieve is to create a test case where it opens a terminal (using mac) and type in some commands to run it like for example:

```
cd /documents/pem/key.pem
connect to -my server via SSH@method
sudo su
yum install php7
yum install mysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research. I did not found any resources or any people that is looking for the same thing I am. I think this is officially, No. The answer to this is, it is not possible.

Comment: I think opening a terminator is kind of desktop app automation. Unfortunately, Katalon has not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone, and with custom keywords you can achieve what you want. Here is an example showing a test of a command line app. You could do the same thing to call any command line script you wish. Think of a *runCmd* keyword, or a *runCmdWithOutput* to grab the output and run various asserts on it.

```
@Keyword
def pdfMetadata(String input) {
    KeywordUtil.logInfo("input: ${input}")

    def csaHome = System.getenv("CSA_HOME")
    def cmd = "cmd /c ${csaHome}/bin/csa -pdfmetadata -in \"${projectPath}${input}\"";
    runCmd(cmd)
}

def runCmd(String cmd) {
    KeywordUtil.logInfo("cmd: ${cmd}")

    def proc = cmd.execute();
    def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
    def errStream = new StringBuffer()
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, errStream);
    println(outputStream.toString());
    println(errStream.toString())

    if(proc.exitValue() != 0){
        KeywordUtil.markFailed("Out:" + outputStream.toString() + ", Err: " + errStream.toString())
    }
}
```

You can then use this in a test case:

```
CustomKeywords.'CSA.pdfMetadata'('/src/pdf/empty.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another custom keyword! It is takes the file name and path, and if you don't give it a path, it search for the file in the project root directory. It export the batch file's output in a batch_reports folder in your project folder, you need to create that in advance.

```
@Keyword
    def runPostmanBatch(String batchName , String batchPath){


        // source: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

        String firstParameter = "cmd /c " + batchName;
        String  secondParameter =  batchPath;

        if (batchPath == ""){
            secondParameter = RunConfiguration.getProjectDir();
            }

        try {
            KeywordUtil.logInfo("Executing " + firstParameter + " at " +  secondParameter)
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        firstParameter , null, new File(secondParameter));

                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.append(line + "\n");
                }

                int exitVal = process.waitFor();

                Date atnow = new Date()
                String now = atnow.format('yy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss')
                String report_path = RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/postman_reports/" + RunConfiguration.getExecutionSourceName() + "_" + now + ".txt"
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(report_path));
                writer.write(output.toString());
                writer.close();
                KeywordUtil.logInfo("postman report at: " + report_path)
                if (exitVal == 0) {

                    println("Success!"); 
                    println(output); 
                    KeywordUtil.markPassed("Ran successfully")                  
                } else {
                KeywordUtil.markFailed("Something went wrong")
                    println(exitVal);
                }



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Katalon Studio from the [command line](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/console-mode-execution.html).

There's a short tutorial [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/generate_command_line.html).

And it will be possible to override Profile Variables via command line execution mode from v5.10 (currently in beta). 
An example given on [Katalon forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/katalon-studio-5-10-beta-release/15344) is:

Simply pass the parameters in command line using: `-g_XXX = XXX`

Below is an example of override an URL variable:

```
-g_URL=http://demoaut.katalon.com
```

Comment: No, what im trying to do is inside katalon i run command line

Comment: Oh, I see. Don't know about that